# MongoDB/PyMongo find_one_and_update and/or find() method doesn't find specified entry, just appends to the end of the collection

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to search in an array in my collection, to find by a key named "id". Both the find() method and find_one_and_update() don't return the entry I'm trying to find. The collection is structured like so:

```
"_id" : {stuff},
"events":[{
  "id":"12345",
  "date":"01/01"
}, {
  "id":"12346",
  "date":"02/02"
}]
```

Trying find() as:

```
result = db.get_collection("events").find({"events.id" : "12345"})
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Prints out the entire collection.
Trying to update a specific entry by its id like so will append it to the end.

```
db.get_collection("events").find_one_and_update({"events.id" : "12345"},{"$set" : {"date" : "somedate"}})
```

Looks like this afterwards:

```
    "id":"12346",
    "date":"02/02"
    }], "date" : "somedate"
```

So, what am I doing wrong with updating and finding here? Every other person seems to have no trouble with this part.

Comment: See these examples about updating an array with embedded documents (or objects), like your case: [Update documents in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

Comment: @prasad_ This doesn't help me as I'm doing exactly what the examples say (at least it seems to me I am) and it is not updating the database correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out on my own, needed to specify which object + field to update in the collection:

```
db.get_collection("events").find_one_and_update({"events.id" : "12345"},{"$set" : {"events.$.date" : "somedate"}})
```

Comment: why `events.$.date` instead of `events.date` in `"$set" : {"events.$.date"` ?